# How to post 2D array in jquery ajax where name = "admin[email]"?

Tags: php, jquery

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="settingsForm" id="settingsForm">
        Admin Name: <input type="text" value="Vipul Sharma" name="admin[admin_name]" id="admin_name"><br>
        Admin Email: <input type="text" value="vsharma1@seasiaconsulting.com" name="admin[admin_email]" id="admin_email"><br>
        Site Logo: <input type="file" name="site[logo]" id="site_logo"><img width="150px" height="100px" src="http://localhost/grublies/public/images/Atomic-Bomb-Explosion-600x450.jpg"><br>
        Records Per Page in user side: <input type="text" value="12" name="admin[rpp_user]" id="rpp_user"><br>
        Records Per Page in admin side: <input type="text" value="15" name="admin[rpp_admin]" id="rpp_admin"><br>
        Site Address: <textarea name="admin[site_address]" id="site_address">C 136</textarea><br> <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="" name=""> </form>
```

If i use post method after form submit in php then it creates an array like this

```
Array
(
    [admin] => Array
        (
            [admin_name] => Vipul Sharma
            [admin_email] => vsharma1@seasiaconsulting.com
            [rpp_user] => 12
            [rpp_admin] => 15
            [site_address] => C 136
        )

)
```

but I want this same array to be posted via jQuery ajax but unfortunately its considering admin[admin_name] as a variable . I used jQuery serialize, it didn't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you I have changed some attributes in you HTML see form submit carefully

```
<html>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script> 
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainfomr">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="settingsForm" id="settingsForm">
        Admin Name: <input type="text" value="Vipul Sharma" name="admin[admin_name]" id="admin_name"><br>
        Admin Email: <input type="text" value="vsharma1@seasiaconsulting.com" name="admin[admin_email]" id="admin_email"><br>
        Site Logo: <input type="file" name="site[logo]" id="site_logo"><br>
        Records Per Page in user side: <input type="text" value="12" name="admin[rpp_user]" id="rpp_user"><br>
        Records Per Page in admin side: <input type="text" value="15" name="admin[rpp_admin]" id="rpp_admin"><br>
        Site Address: <textarea name="admin[site_address]" id="site_address">C 136</textarea><br> <input type="button" value="Submit" id="formsubmit" name=""> </form>
</body>
<script>
    $("#mainfomr").on("click", "#formsubmit", function(event){

        var order = $("#settingsForm").serialize()
     $.post("yourphpfile.php",order, function(data){

     });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```